# MBtiles ext for GeoServer can't find the version I need

Tags: geoserver, tilemill

I'm running geoserver 2.10.3 as local host just for development prior to pushing things into production on a public facing site. I generated tiles in TileMill but i can't find the the matching version I need for geoServer.All of the subfolders here are all contain 2.12 versions:

http://ares.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/master/

Does anyone know where i can find the 2.10.3 version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://ares.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/2.10.x/

Just go up one folder from the link you provided.
The plugin is a "community" one, so you can find it at http://ares.opengeo.org/geoserver/2.10.x/community-latest/geoserver-2.10-SNAPSHOT-mbtiles-plugin.zip

or use the release folder http://ares.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/release/2.10.3/

Comment: Thanks but I don't see the mbtiles plugin in here anywhere

Comment: @ShaunO see updated answer with direct link

Comment: Got it working after installing the WPS extension. I thought the generalized version (2.10) was causing the error but after installing the WPS extension it worked fine. Thanks!